# Как хранить и использовать временные данные в запросе Oracle

Tags: oracle

Мне необходимо реализовать следующую задачу:

У меня есть некий сложный алгоритм, который рассчитывает предварительные данные и которые необходимо сложить и запомнить для последующего многократного использования.
Пусть, для примера, это будет вот такой простой запрос:

```
Select ObjectId into #tmp from TableWithObjectIds
```

После этого у меня есть сложный рекурсивный запрос, который рассчитывает какие конкретно записи необходимо обновить и обновляет их
Запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
WITH "HR" ("VAL1","VAL2")
AS (
    Select Val1, Val2 
      from Tbl1
    where valX in (select ObjectId from #tmp) 
union all 
    Select Val1, Val2 
      from Tbl1
      join HR on Tbl1.Val1 <> HR.Val1
    where valX in (select ObjectId from #tmp) 
    ) UPDATE TableX
      SET TableX.Cell1 = Val1,
          TableX.Call2 = Val2
     from HR 
    where Table1.Val1 = HR.VVal1

update Teable3
   set ...
  from #tmp
 where ...
```

Собственно вопрос: как это реализовать на Oracle?

Comment: Что-то суть проблемы непонятна... что мешает использовать показанный "вот такой простой запрос" как ещё одно CTE? само собой перед остальными.. а если этот результат надо использовать в нескольких запросах - ну так сложить его во временную (или на время созданную статическую) таблицу.

Comment: Запихнуть "простой" запрос в начало CTE не дает тот факт, что основной CTE запрос рекурсивный, и что рекурсивный запрос в CTE может быть только один и только первый. А что касается использования временных таблиц - никак не получается реализовать ...  если покажете, как сделать - буду признателен. Ну и постоянные таблицы использовать для хранения временных данных это как-то совсем не правильно ...

Comment: *рекурсивный запрос в CTE может быть только один и только первый* Кто Вам сказал эту глупость? https://dbfiddle.uk/BKr8gY0o

Comment: Спасибо! Это классное решение! к сожалению в вопросе я забыл уточнить, что мне нужно два update сделать ...  один из CTE второй из того "простого" набора.  (вопрос поправил)

Comment: *мне нужно два update сделать* Ууу... Оракл - это не Постгресс. Тогда промежуточное сохранение в таблицу - единственное решение.

Comment: Ок, пусть будет временная таблица, как это написать? PS: я MSSQL знаю, в Oracle мои знания пока крайне малы (

Comment: Да как обычно. CREATE TABLE ... INSERT SELECT .. UPDATE t1 .. UPDATE t2 .. DROP TABLE.